# Inequality with large exponents, RMM 2016

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $x,y$ be positive reals, with $x+y^{2016} \ge 1$. Prove that $x^{2016}+y > 1-\frac{1}{100}$.

Wolframalpha gives that the minimum possible value for $x^{2016}+y$ is about $0.997415$.

How would one solve this inequality with simple calculations?

Comment: Nice question. Where did you find it?

Comment: This is a problem from Romania Masters of Mathematics 2016, Problem 4.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. Someone should verify this.

Clearly it suffices to check $0<x<1$ and $0<y<0.99$.

Also, we can let $x+y^{2016}=1$ as it only strengthens the condition.

It suffices to show that $(1-y^{2016})^{2016}+y>0.99$.

By Bernoulli's Inequality, it suffices to show that $1-2016y^{2016}+y>0.99$

Take $f(y)=y-2016y^{2016}$ - then $f'(y)=1-2016^2y^{2015}$.

Therefore, $f(y)$ increases in $[0,\frac{1}{\sqrt[2015]{2016^2}}]$.

Now we just need to check $f(y)>-0.01$ for $y=0$ and $y=0.99$. $y=0$ case is trivial.

We now need to show that $(0.99)^{2016} < \frac{1}{2016}$.

This is equivalent with $(1+\frac{1}{99})^{2016} > 2016$, but we have $$(1+\frac{1}{99})^{2016} = ((1+\frac{1}{99})^{99})^{\frac{2016}{99}} \ge 2^{\frac{2016}{99}} \ge 2^{15} > 2016$$so we are done.